# Does anyone have Delzell's Thesis on Bad Points of Forms?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, real-algebraic-geometry

Since a number of papers ([e.g. this one](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~reznick/paper30.pdf)) treating denominators in Hilbert's 17th problem point to E.G. Strauss's unpublished letter to G. Kriesel or to Chapter 5 of Delzell's Thesis, which contains an extensive history of "bad points" for real forms, it would be nice if either of these things could be readily found online. It would also be great to have access to the paper: Delzell, C. N., *Unavoidable singularities when writing polynomials as sums of squares of real rational functions*. Which is cited as in preparation many places...

> **Question:** Are there any papers freely available online that treat in detail bad points for homogeneous positive semidefinite forms? If so, where are they?

Comment: there is no legal copy of the thesis online, because of copyright restrictions, however, you can order a copy by following this [link](http://dissexpress.umi.com/dxweb/results.html?QryTxt=&By=delzell&Title=hilbert&pubnum=)

Comment: I'd still like some kind of free online treatment, since I'm only looking for some basic things, like how to tell whether a given polynomial has a bad point, or whether the "specified zero" must be a real zero, etc. I asked because it's really too bad that nothing at all can be found about this online...(I hope I am wrong!)

Comment: All I can find is in Example 1 in Section 2.1 of http://www4.ncsu.edu/~kaltofen/bibliography/09/KLYZ09.pdf

Comment: Made CW on OP's request.

Comment: Thanks, Todd! I'm not asking anything mathematical here, which is why I requested CW. It's a pure reference request.

Comment: Could you ILL his Inventiones paper? (I don't have access to that volume, or I'd scan it for you.) The NYPL has that volume, but you'd have to wait for them to get it out of storage. - Jeff http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01388465

Answer (score 4):

Delzell's thesis is available here: [http://www.math.ens.fr/~benoist/textes/Delzell.pdf](http://www.math.ens.fr/%7Ebenoist/textes/Delzell.pdf) .

Comment: Cool to see this.  Dr. Delzell supervised some independent studies on set theory for me during my senior year at LSU, and was a key factor on convincing me to go to grad school back in 1989.

Comment: Thank you Olivier!